# highchart tooltip, use the date on the tooltip rather than mouse's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am currently working on the highchart tooltip.

I have built one chart, the x-Axis will show the dates and y-Axis will show the value. When I click mouse and drag it, it will zoom in the area enclosed in the new highchart. This works well. However, there is one issue that when I drag mouse, the boundary of the new chart is determined by the position of the mouse rather than the line where the tooltip show upon.

For example, when my mouse move to a position between `2015-04-05` and `2015-04-06`, my mouse position in x axis is some float value and I can see that when the mouse cross the mid-line (the middle position) between positions of these two dates on x-Axis, the date on the tooltip changes. This cause me some trouble that, the date value determined by my mouse position (and this is what I need to send to server) is different from what I see on the tooltip. The tooltip may show `2015-04-06`, but the value (after rounding the position of mouse) sent to server would be `2015-04-07`.

What I want to do is to send the value showed on the tooltip to server rather than the value got from mouse.

I can see that, in tooltip formatter, there is a `this.x`. But I am not sure how to extract this value and using this value for server request?

Comment: can you show some code and possibly a fiddle